# pointers and string parsing in c

Tags: c, pointers, string-parsing

I was wondering if somebody could explain me how pointers and string parsing works. I know that I can do something like the following in a loop but I still don't follow very well how it works.

```
  for (a = str;  * a;  a++) ...
```

For instance, I'm trying to get the last integer from the string. if I have a string as `const char *str = "some string here 100 2000";`

Using the method above, how could I parse it and get the last integer of the string (2000), knowing that the last integer (2000) may vary.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everybody! It all becomes much clearer now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `for (a = str;  * a;  a++) ...`

This works by starting a pointer `a` at the beginning of the string, until dereferencing `a` is implicitly converted to false, incrementing `a` at each step.

Basically, you'll walk the array until you get to the NUL terminator that's at the end of your string (`\0`) because the NUL terminator implicitly converts to false - other characters do not.

> Using the method above, how could I parse it and get the last integer of the string (2000), knowing that the last integer (2000) may vary.

You're going to want to look for the *last space before* the `\0`, then you're going to want to call a function to convert the remaining characters to an integer.  See `strtol`.

Consider this approach:

- find the end of the string (using that loop)
- search backwards for a space.
- use that to call `strtol`.

-

```
for (a = str; *a; a++);  // Find the end.
while (*a != ' ') a--;   // Move back to the space.
a++;  // Move one past the space.
int result = strtol(a, NULL, 10);
```

Or alternatively, just keep track of the start of the last token:

```
const char* start = str;
for (a = str; *a; a++) {     // Until you hit the end of the string.
  if (*a == ' ') start = a;  // New token, reassign start.
}
int result = strtol(start, NULL, 10);
```

This version has the benefit of not requiring a space in the string.

Comment: This code is broken if the string contains no spaces. It will loop past the beginning of the string, possibly into invalid addresses, in which case it will crash.

Comment: if the str is correctly null terminated, `a = str + strlen(str)` points to the byte past the last byte of the string (the null byte); almost the same as the `for` loop but more readable, I think; moreover instead of `*a != ' '` you can use isspace

Comment: @R.. : That's true, but given how the question was phrased, I think it's a safe assumption.

Comment: @ShinTakezou : Also true :) I considered using `strlen`, but the OP said "using the above method", so I did... OTOH, `isspace` probably would be more clear.

Comment: @R.. : Thanks for the idea, I've added a version that doesn't require a space.

Comment: @Stephen: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127722/pointers-and-string-parsing-in-c/3129035#3129035 which uses `strrchr()` rather than rolling your own loop

Answer (score 3):

You just need to implement a simple state machine with two states, e.g

```
#include <ctype.h>

int num = 0; // the final int value will be contained here
int state = 0; // state == 0 == not parsing int, state == 1 == parsing int

for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
{
    if (state == 0) // if currently in state 0, i.e. not parsing int
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) // if we just found the first digit character of an int
        {
            num = s[i] - '0'; // discard any old int value and start accumulating new value
            state = 1; // we are now in state 1
        }
        // otherwise do nothing and remain in state 0
    }
    else // currently in state 1, i.e. parsing int
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) // if this is another digit character
        {
            num = num * 10 + s[i] - '0'; // continue accumulating int
            // remain in state 1...
        }
        else // no longer parsing int
        {
            state = 0; // return to state 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuck :)  This deserves 3 lines of code, with one parse instead of analyzing each character.

Comment: This is an inefficient method; it parses all strings and tosses away all but the last.  And you should call strlen() only once and save that in a temp var, instead of calling it on every iteration, as this code does (the compiler *may* optimize this for you if the string is a `const char *`).

Comment: @Tim/@Stephen: are you familiar with the term *premature optimisation* ? The above code was written for clarity and to illustrate the concept of states in a parser (even though in this case there are only two states) - the OP is a noob and needs to understand the basic concepts, not worry about micro-optimisation or writing the tersest possible code.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe: who said anything abut requiring C89/C90 compatibility ? C99 has been around for over 10 years now, and most C compilers have supported C++/C99-style comments for much longer than that. What is the problem ? And does it really warrant a down-vote ???

Comment: @Paul R : I'm quite familiar with the term. :)  My "yuck" wasn't really referring to the inefficiencies, it was about the complexity of your solution.  Look how many branches there are - that's where bugs usually lie, look how many comments you have to explain it!  It's a clever solution, but wayyyyy overkill for this problem.

Comment: @Paul R : By the way, putting `strlen` in the for-loop turns an O(n) problem into O(n^2).  That's hardly premature optimization.  (Of course, this depends on how clever the compiler optimizes...)  I didn't vote you down - clearly it works... I'd just prefer something simpler.

Comment: @Stephen: no need to second-guess the compiler - gcc is smart enough to cache the result of strlen, as should any halfway-decent compiler.

Comment: @Paul R, I did not downvote. I never downvote unless it is really bad. It just made me sad to see C99 being further promoted. :) I don't care for C99 and it is hardly fully supported, even if the comment style is. I prefer strict ANSI C, although I have to give up on that in certain situations (kernel programming). Also, I'm not sure gcc caches the result of strlen, any documentation on this?

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe: 3 downvotes now - all from anonymous curmudgeons apparently - never mind. I'm not sure why you're so opposed to C99, but the // comments predate it anyway - even people who write C89 with gcc tend to use // comments (i.e. not strict ANSI). As for caching the result of strlen - I checked this by looking at the output from gcc -S.

Comment: Well there's an upvote. I think its an ok answer. Interesting on the caching.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered already but all the answers thus far are recreating code that is available in the Standard C Library.    Here is what I would use by taking advantage of `strrchr()`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    const char* input = "some string here 100 2000";
    char* p;
    long l = 0;

    if(p = strrchr(input, ' '))
        l = strtol(p+1, NULL, 10);

    printf("%ld\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (a = str;  * a;  a++)...
```

is equivalent to

```
  a=str;
  while(*a!='\0') //'\0' is NUL, don't confuse it with NULL which is a macro
  {
      ....
      a++;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The loop you've presented just goes through all characters (string is a pointer to the array of 1-byte chars that ends with 0). For parsing you should use `sscanf` or better `C++`'s string and string stream.